# PrimeNG p-dialog modal in Angular application blocks background and the dialog window itself

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-dialog

I am using a **p-dialog** **PrimeNG** component in my **Angular 5** application like this:

```
<p-dialog [(visible)]="displayModal" [modal]="true" [width]="500" [height]="450" >
    <p-header> Title </p-header>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="approverComment">Comment</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="approverComment" rows="8"></textarea>
    </div>
    <p-footer>
        <button type="button" pButton icon="fa-close" (click)="displayModal=false" label="Cancel"></button>
    </p-footer>
</p-dialog>
```

It's nothing out of the ordinary. If I make the dialog modal (like above) then instead of blocking out only the background, even my dialog window is greyed-out, and I cannot press my **Cancel** button. The only way to exit is to press the **Esc** key.

The dialog window works fine if I don't make it modal but I'd like to make it modal. Anyone had this issue with `p-dialog`? I've search all over for awhile now but could not see this issue posted before.

I'm using **Angular 5** with **PrimeNG 5.2.0-rc.2**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you tried adding

```
[appendTo]=“‘body’”
```

The pDialog can be a bit of a nightmare. I would get this problem when the dialog tag was inside a container.

Comment: It is occurring for me in the p-confirmDialog also can you please provide a code sample of how to use [appendTo]=“‘body’” this property ?

Comment: @NasrulBharathi hey! Haven’t tested this but it is in the docs for confirmDialog. Should be <p-confirmDialog [appendTo]=“‘body“ ....

Comment: nice one. I had a dialog with a form field in it. I could not focus the field, click in it or tab to it or anything. Could not enter data. This fixed it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Late Answer, but might help someone

Adding `appendTo ="body"`  will make the blur effect of background screen fix .

To remove the background blur fully, ***remove the following*** parameter from p-dialog  `[modal]="true"`